# Writing a function to combine dataframes by rows

Tags: r

I need some help with a homework problem. It is asking that I make a function which can take a data frame, and provide the mean, median, and standard deviation of each column specified, and the count the number of "NA's" that are present. For example,

df1

```
 1. 12 15 16 17
 2. NA 24 18 NA
 3. 16 14 19 20
```

**Function(df[3])**

The should return the dataframe:

```
 1. mean med sd NA's
 2. 17.6 17.5 1.52 0
```

So far, the function have is:

```
table1 <- function(dat){
  average <- mean(dat)
  med <- median(dat)
  standard_deviation <- sd(dat)
  x <-cbind(average, med, standard_deviation)
  x}
```

However, it seems that R keeps responding with:
"Error in mean(dat) : object 'patient' not found"
Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data frame?

Comment: calling `table1(iris$Sepal.Length)` yielded correct looking results to me.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to write a function which takes a data frame and a column index and return the desired results.

```
summ_col <- function(df, colindex = 1) {
  mean <- mean(df[[colindex]], na.rm = TRUE)
  median <- median(df[[colindex]], na.rm = TRUE)
  sd <- sd(df[[colindex]], na.rm = TRUE)
  nas <- sum(is.na((df[[colindex]])))
  return (data.frame(mean = mean, median = median, sd = sd, nas = nas))
}
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = c(12, NA, 16), x2 = c(15, 24, 14),
                  x3 = c(16, 18, 19), x4 = c(17, NA, 20))
summ_col(df1, 3)
```

Note that you can use `summ_col(df1[3])` as `df1[3]` will create a new data frame consisting only of the 3rd column of df1, and the default argument of 1 for `colindex` ensures that it summarizes the appropriate column.

Comment: One of the restrictions is that the function can only have one argument, can you recommend me something?

Comment: Write a wrapper function summ_col2 <- function(df) {
  summ_col(df)
} and put summ_col inside the definition of this function.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but do you mean this?

Comment: summ_col <- function(df) {
  mean <- mean(df[[colindex]], na.rm = TRUE)
  median <- median(df[[colindex]], na.rm = TRUE)
  sd <- sd(df[[colindex]], na.rm = TRUE)
  nas <- sum(is.na((df[[colindex]])))
  summ_col2 <- function(df) {summ_col(df) } 
  return (data.frame(mean = mean, median = median, sd = sd, nas = nas))
}

Comment: Almost - this will not work as you are not including colindex as an argument in summ_col. You can put my original solution inside summ_col - change the name of my function to summ_col2. Also add `return summ_col2(df)` at the end of your function.